# How to conditional format ONLY the first row that meets a condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, google-spreadsheets

I have an amortization table with a date next to each row. How do I highlight ONLY the first row that is a larger date than today's date?

Let's say the date column starts at A13. Obviously this...

```
=A$13>=today()
```

Would highlight EVERY row that is a date later than today.

I've been racking my brain since yesterday and came up with absurdly complex logic trees that almost achieve what I want, but so complex that I'm certain there MUST be a better way.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: After posting, I had this idea: =AND($A13>=today(), $A13<today()+31), but in some cases it will highlight 2 rows. Even with +30. +29 sometimes doesn't highlight any. All because each month can be a different number of days.

Comment: MINIFS would do this if your excel supports that newer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using A13 as the start of the column:

```
=COUNTIF($A$13:$A13,">="&today())=1
```

This will now highlight only the first instance where the date is greater than or equal to today.

[image]

Comment: That did it! I can't say I know WHY it works, but I guess it does. What is the "&" doing?

Comment: It concatenates a two parts into one string

Answer (score 2):

The newer MINIIFS should be able to do this.

```
=$a13=minifs($a:$a, $a:$a, “>=”&today())
```